# Jest encountered an unexpected token in a test.tsx file [React-native]

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, babeljs, ts-jest

I see a lot of people are facing this issue. I have tried out various ways but still not able to figure it out.

Getting the following error in my terminal:

FAIL  **tests**/App.test.tsx
● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

/Users/mmt10901/Desktop/Code/B2B-Shopfront-Mobile/__tests__/App.test.tsx:37
    const component = renderer.create(<App_1.NavBody />);
                                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)
```

The following is my Jest config:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: "ts-jest",
    testEnvironment: "node",
    setupFiles: ['./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js'],

    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setupTests.js"],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules/(?!(react-native|@react-native|@babel|ts-js)/)",
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
            '<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js',
        '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js',
    },
    // transform: {},
    transform: {
        "\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
        "\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
};
```

The following is my Babel Config:

```
module.exports = (api) => {
  api.cache(false);

  return {
    presets: [
      "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
    ],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module:react-native-dotenv",
        {
          envName: "APP_ENV",
          moduleName: "@env",
          // paths: {
          //    "@env": ["node_modules/react-native-dotenv"],
          //    "react-native-dotenv": ["node_modules/react-native-dotenv"]
          // },
          path: ".env",
          safe: false,
          allowUndefined: true,
          verbose: false,
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

tsConfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "checkJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    ".eslintrc.js",
    "*.ts",
    "*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "*/*.d.tsx",
    "*/**.d.ts",
    "./tsconfig.json",
    "./babel.config.js",
    "./jest.config.js"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "esModuleInterop": true
}
```

I am using "react-native": "0.71.7"

Please help me as it is a basic setup and I have been busting my mind since past 2 days, trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue where Jest fails due to an unexpected token on the opening `<` of a JSX tag, it often comes down to setting the right React runtime. To do this, try configuring `@babel/preset-react` with `runtime: "automatic"` (and installing `@babel/preset-react` if needed).

I.e., in a normal .babelrc file, you want something like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-react", { runtime: "automatic" }]
  ]
}
```